# Elegant ways of proving: If $v_1, \ldots, v_j$ are linearly independent then $v_i \notin span(v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1}, v_{i+1}, ..., v_j)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Elegant ways of proving: If $v_1, \ldots, v_j$ are linearly independent then $v_i \notin span(v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1}, v_{i+1}, ..., v_j)$.

Idea:

Suppose I can write $c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_{i-1}v_{i-1} + c_{i+1}v_{i+1} + \ldots c_j v_j = v_i$. Then $c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_{i-1}v_{i-1} + c_{i+1}v_{i+1} + \ldots c_j v_j -v_i= 0$ is a non-trivial relation among the vectors ($-1$ is not zero), a contradiction, since the vectors only have the trivial relation.

Could this be proven without contradiction ?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is good and contradiction is not necessary, because you can use the contrapositive.

---

It is not restrictive to assume $i=1$. If
$$
v_1=c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n
$$
then
$$
v_1-c_2v_2-\dots-c_nv_n=0
$$
so the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer using contraposition - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a direct proof:**

Let 
$$F=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_j)$$
and
$$E=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$$
then
$$E=F+\operatorname{span}(v_i)\tag 1$$
and since $(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ is linearly independant then it's basis of $E$ then
$$\dim E=j\quad\text{and}\quad\dim F=j-1$$
so
$$\dim E=\dim F+\dim\operatorname{span}(v_i)$$
hence the sum in $(1)$ is direct and then $$\operatorname{span}(v_i)\cap F=\{0\}$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Why can you conclude the sum is direct ? (Thanks for your response)

Comment: We have this result: If 
$$E=F+G$$
and 
$$\dim E=\dim F+\dim G$$
then
$$E=F\oplus G$$

Comment: Thank you, I will have to look this result up as it's quite useful. Does it has some special name ?

Comment: No it hasn't a special name, it's just one of characterizations of the direct sum that we study. @NicolasLykkeIversen